# mapEithers function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, map-function

How does the following function work:

```
mapEithers :: (a -> Either b c) -> [a] -> Either b [c]
mapEithers f (x:xs) = case mapEithers f xs of
                        Left err -> Left err
                        Right ys -> case f x of
                                      Left err -> Left err
                                      Right y -> Right (y:ys)
mapEithers _ _ = Right []
```

In the first case expression (`case mapEithers f xs`), how does it pattern match with `Left` and `Right` values when the function `f` has not be applied to the elements of the list yet.

Comment: It's matching against the result of the recursive call to `mapEithers` which is an `Either b [c]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is classic recursion, we apply `mapEithers` to a sublist yielding something of the type `Either b [c]`, if it's `Left b`, the we just propagate that through.

If it's `Right cs`. Then we apply `f` to the head of the list. If this yields an error, we drop everything and propagate that up, if it's `Right c`, then the result is `Right (c : cs)`.

And because we need a recusive base case, an empty list is `Right []`.

Comment: But when you apply `mapEithers` to a sub list, then `mapEithers` again gets called due to recursion.  This continues till the list becomes empty, in which case it should return `Right []`. But this doesn't happen. What am I inferring wrong ?

Comment: @Sibi To the contrary, this is exactly what happens http://ideone.com/gWIHlG. What do you see instead?

Comment: Are you missing the second part where after it becomes `Right []` everthing is built back up? See the second little paragraph

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this can be written more idiomatically with a `fold`. In real Haskell code, you rarely see explicit recursion. Rather, we have a bunch of functions (among other `fold`, `replicateM`, `map`, `filter`) which do the "heavy lifting" for us, and we only need to provide some parameters that customize them a little when we use them.

In your case, you have two `Either` values – the result from the rest of the list and the result from the current value. If both are `Right` you want them together in a list, and if they are `Left` you want to only keep the error message.

What I described can in Haskell be written as

```
(:) <$> f elem <*> rest
```

This will return the `Left` value if either `f elem` is a `Left` or if `rest` is a `Left`. If both are `Right`, it will extract the list from `rest` and the value from `f elem` and create a new list of both.

Put into a `fold` call, this means that `mapEithers` would in the real world be more likely to be written as

```
mapEithers f = foldr (\elem rest -> (:) <$> f elem <*> rest) (Right [])
```

Edit: I just realised it can be even simpler with a few additioal transformations. (My Haskell-fu isn't strong enough to be able to read this fluently though...)

```
mapEithers f = foldr (liftA2 (:) . f) (Right [])
```

Comment: `mapEither` is also *almost* the same as a use of `mapM`, except that the latter chooses to shortcut on the first `Left` result instead of the last one as `mapEither` does.